# How to reset the orientation of main window in Titanium using Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

My main window(index.xml) has its orientation properties set like this:

```
orientationModes: [
        Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
        Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT
    ],
```

Now i have a button in main window,which opens another window(say `Gallery.xml`) after clicking on it.

Orientation modes for Gallery.xml is :

```
orientationModes: [
    Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
    Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
]
```

Whenever i tap on this button, Gallery.xml opens up in landscape mode & after closing the `Gallery.xml` window, main window again turns into portrait mode.

But this series of orientation works only for two or three times,after that main window sets out to only landscape mode & then never gets changed.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me that how should i handle this functionality,to keep main window in portrait mode & gallery window in landscape mode only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to keep main window in portrait mode & gallery window in landscape mode only ?

You can use [orientation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-orientation) property of the window.

So in your `main.xml` or `main.tss` add this `orientation` property in the root window. Example:

```
<Window id="main" orientation=Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT >
    <Button>Test</Button>
</Window>
```

Similarly in `Gallery.xml` or `Gallery.tss` add `orientation` property in window to restrict in landscape mode. Example:

```
<Window id="gallery" orientation=Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT >
    <Button>Test</Button>
</Window>
```

Comment: i tried the same thing before but i think this was the issue of Ti SDK as i updated the SDK to 3.4.0 GA & then clean the project & rebuild, it worked then..